# Can't Access TextBoxes in other pages of GridView

Tags: c#, devexpress, asp.net-2.0, aspxgridview

I have an `ASPxGridView` with a column containg `ASPxTextBox`

```
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Capacity" FieldName="Capacity" VisibleIndex="4" >
    <DataItemTemplate>
        <dxe:ASPxTextBox ID="txtCapacity" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Capacity") %>'>
        </dxe:ASPxTextBox>
    </DataItemTemplate>
</dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

I added a button for saving the capacity.

I use `GetRowValues(index, field_name)` to access other fields and `FindRowCellTemplateControl(index, column, id)` to be able to get `txtCapacity`'s value. But the problem is, when paging is involved, I can't access the textboxes in other pages.

Any ideas about this? Thanks

EDIT v.1

Here is my code where I invoke `FindRowCellTemplateControl()`

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Capacity> capacityList = new List<Capacity>();

    for (int i = 0; gvCapacity.VisibleRowCount > i; i++)
    {
        Capacity c = new Capacity();
        c.Id = (int)gvCapacity.GetRowValues(i, "Id");

        ASPxTextBox txtCapacity = (ASPxTextBox)gvCapacity.FindRowCellTemplateControl(i, (GridViewDataColumn)gvCapacity.Columns["Capacity"], "txtCapacity");
        c.Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtCapacity.Text);

        capacityList.Add(c);
    }

    //Save Capacity
    //...
}
```

Comment: Show some code where you call the `FindRowCellTemplateControl(index, column, id)`, plus; cant you just loop through your underlying datasource to get the `Capacities` values? I see you use binding.

Comment: @Rami.Shareef: Thanks but I can't just loop thru the datasource to get the `Capacities` values, because they are being changed in this page (that's why Capacities are displayed in text boxes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASPxGridView creates template controls for an active page only. So, it is impossible to get a reference to the non-existing controls via the **FindRowCellTemplateControl** method.

See the http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q341997 discussion in the DX support center to learn more on how to solve this issue.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the link. I'll mark this as the answer after verification. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless my comment on your question, and if I got your question right then,
you have an `ASPxButton` and you want when `Click` it to get all `Capacities` inside your `ASPxGridView`

try this:

```
protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Loop throug all Pages
    for (int i = 0; i < ASPxGridView1.PageCount; i++)
    {
        //Select current page
        ASPxGridView1.PageIndex = i;

        //Loop through all rows inisde the page
        for (int J = 0; J < ASPxGridView1.SettingsPager.PageSize; J++)
        {
             //Get currnt TextBox
             DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxTextBox txtbox = 
             ASPxGridView1.FindRowCellTemplateControl(J,
             (DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.GridViewDataColumn)ASPxGridView1.Columns["Capacitiy"],
             "txtCapacity") as DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxTextBox;

             //Do your logic here
         }
    }
}
```

I'm still encourage you to get your data through your underlying datasource